# Applying Margin To Report Pages

Tags: c#, printing, crystal-reports

I want to apply User Input Values for Margin to affect the Report pages that goes to printing in crystal report 2008 XI .
Like 
     top margin  : 0.56 
     left margin : 0.25
in my c# code i simply do this
                       "**string top=txtTopMargin*1000   eg 0.56*1000**"
                       "**string left=txtLeftMargin*1000  eg 0.25*1000**"

and pass these values to the *rdoc.PrintOption.ApplyMargin(Left,Top,0,0)** of reportdocument of c# . same code works in Visual 6.0 but my code not works.
I dont know **which conversion unit is applying** when i pass the value to applymargin function..
i m totally stuck please help me to solve this problem.....

Comment: What do you mean by "Report Pages"? (There are many many reporting tools out there, any answer is likely to be tool specific.)

Comment: Crystal Report Tool Mr Richard

Comment: i mean when i press the Print button of application .the pages of crystal report directly go to printer for printing.in PrintButton code i use the ApplyMargin function of report document which take the values and apply margin..of specified values..hope you get my point..

Comment: OK, so I've now tagged the Q better. Hopefully someone who knows Crystal Reports will be along to answer it.